# How to handle SSL certificates for development machine without a custom server on Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, ssl, next.js, next.js13

My local development environment requires a ssl for authentication or sign into my identity provider. After an investigation I relaized we can do it via a `customer server` for **nextjs13**.

**Problem**:
Based on Nextjs documentation, if we define a custom server we will lose some important performance optimization:

> Before deciding to use a custom server, please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.
> A custom server cannot be deployed on Vercel.
> Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server

Then Google Bard suggested to use following attribues inside `.env` file:

**.env**

```
HTTPS=true
NEXT_PUBLIC_HTTPS=true
HTTPS_KEY=/certificate/RootCA.key
HTTPS_CERT=/certificate/RootCA.crt
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost


127.0.0.1 dev.exmaple.com
127.0.0.1 dev.exmaple.de
127.0.0.1 dev.exmaple.es
```

I get this error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection local.exmaple.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

NOTE: Let's suppose that I issued the keys for dev.example.com.

Comment: Can you also use docker / nginx locally?